# how to get data from one textbox to another textbox in dynamically generated html table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

below is my code. in that code when i enter 3 in txtbox and click copy.then same table will be generated 3 times. if i enter name and id in txtbox 1 and 2 and click get data then it will be set to txtbox 3 and 4.it works fine only with first table. the problem is it is not working with dynamic tables.help me!!
the code as follows,

```js
function copytbl() {
  var i, j;
  j = document.getElementById("txtbox").value;
  for (i = 0; i < j - 1; i++) {
    var row = document.getElementById("tblbdy"); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl"); // find table to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
  }
}

function getdata() {
  document.getElementById("txtbox3").value = document.getElementById("txtbox1").value;
  document.getElementById("txtbox4").value = document.getElementById("txtbox2").value;
}

function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  height: 90px;
  text-align: left;
}

tr.noBorder td {
  border-right-style: hidden;
  border-left-style: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtbox" name="textbox" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<button type="button" onclick="copytbl()">COPY</button><br>
<br>
<table id="tbl" style="width:100%">
  <tbody id="tblbdy">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td colspan="3">Age</td>
      <td>Sex</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        Name:<br>
        <input type="text" id="txtbox1" name="textbox" /><br> Id:
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="txtbox2" name="textbox" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" /><br>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">Footer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="noBorder">
      <td>
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="getdata()">GET DATA</button><br><br> Name:
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="txtbox3" name="textbox" /><br> Id:
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="txtbox4" name="textbox" /><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: This is because you have multiple iterations of the same ID. You're cloning the html and all of it's id's. You need to clone the html and then re-assign id's

Comment: am a beginner i dnt knw how to do it.pls give some example

Comment: I've quickly put an example together for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `id`'s you are using into `classes`. Then parse the new `tbody` id you generate into the `getdata` Function

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/kplcode/bt5da5go/2/

```
function copytbl() {
  var i, j;
  j = document.getElementById("txtbox").value;
  for (i = 0; i < j - 1; i++) {
    var newId = "newID-"+(document.querySelectorAll('.tblbdy-ele').length+i);
    var row = document.getElementById("tblbdy"); // find row to copy
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl"); // find table to append to
    var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
    clone.id = newId; // change id or other attributes/contents
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    var getDataBtn = document.getElementById(newId).getElementsByClassName("getDataBtn")[0]
    getDataBtn.onclick = function() {
        getdata(newId);
    };
  }
}

function getdata(id) {
    var table = document.getElementById(id);
  document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName("txtbox3")[0].value = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName("txtbox1")[0].value;
  document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName("txtbox4")[0].value = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName("txtbox2")[0].value;
}

function isNumber(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: i tried it bt it wont work for me. 
am a beginner i dnt knw how to do it.pls give some example

Comment: Sash, if this did *not* solve your problem, why did you mark this answer as *accepted*? Also, be more specific. What does *"it wont work me me"* mean exactly?